# wxpython: How can I fill a Notebook tab with a grid created elsewhere?

Tags: python, grid, wxpython, panel, frame

Right now I have a GUI built from wxpython that successfully pulls data from a .csv, populates a wx grid object, and then displays it in a new frame.  I have also successfully got my main window to display some information in the notebook style.  My goal is to make it so that when I run my program, one of the main page tabs contains the same populated grid as the window I previously made. The issue that keeps stumping me is that the grid creation and grid population (two separate things) are done in different classes in a different (but imported) local file.  Additionally, the below code in my program context gives the AttributeError: 'TabPanel' object has no attribute 'con', which makes sense, but I don't

Is this not possible or is there something I am missing (and am I even being clear?)?  Below is what I would guess would be relevant code.  (Incorrect spacing for class and constructor lines just for convenience here.)  Thank you very much!

Tab/Notebook:

```
class TabPanel(wx.Panel):    
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent, id=wx.ID_ANY)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        txtOne = wx.Panel(Employee.EmployeeViewAllFrame(self).show())

        self.sizer.Add(txtOne, 0, wx.ALL , 50)

        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)


class NotebookDemo(wx.Notebook):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Notebook.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, style=
                         wx.BK_DEFAULT
                         #wx.BK_TOP 
                         #wx.BK_BOTTOM
                         #wx.BK_LEFT
                         #wx.BK_RIGHT
                         )

        # Create the first tab and add it to the notebook
        tabOne = TabPanel(self)
        tabOne.SetBackgroundColour("BLUE")
        self.AddPage(tabOne, "Main")

        # Create and add the second tab
        tabTwo = TabPanel(self)
        self.AddPage(tabTwo, "Employees")

        # Create and add the third tab
        self.AddPage(TabPanel(self), "Tasks")
```

Grid/Frame:

```
class empGrid(wx.grid.Grid):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.grid.Grid.__init__(self,parent,size = (1500,1000))
        self.SetDefaultCellOverflow(False)
        self.EnableEditing(False)
        self.EnableDragGridSize(False)
        self.EnableDragRowSize(False)
        self.EnableDragColSize(False)
        self.grid = gridlib.Grid(panel2)
        self.CreateGrid(TOTALEMPLOYEES, 12)
        self.SetColLabelValue(0, "Name")

        self.SetColSize(0, 200)
        self.SetColLabelValue(1, "Grade")
        self.SetColLabelValue(2, "NGID")
        self.SetColLabelValue(3, "MyID")
        self.SetColLabelValue(4, "Skillset1")
        self.SetColSize(4, 110)
        self.SetColLabelValue(5, "Skillset2")
        self.SetColSize(5, 110)
        self.SetColLabelValue(6, "SME")
        self.SetColLabelValue(7, "Org")
        self.SetColLabelValue(8, "Manager")
        self.SetColSize(8, 125)
        self.SetColLabelValue(9, "OfficePriority")
        self.SetColSize(9, 165)
        self.SetColLabelValue(10, "Comments")
        self.SetColSize(10, 200)
        self.SetColLabelValue(11, "Loan?")
        #self.AutoSizeColumns(setAsMin=True)


class EmployeeViewAllFrame(wx.Frame): 
  def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent,title = 'View All Employees',size=(wx.EXPAND,wx.EXPAND))
    self.currentid = ''
    self.currentrow = 0
    self.parent = parent
    #Declare all panels
    self.panelMain = wx.Panel(self,size = (1500, 1000)) 
    self.panelSide = wx.Panel(self,size = (wx.EXPAND, 1000)) 
    #self.panelTitle = wx.Panel(self,size = (1000,30))      
    #self.buttonPanel = wx.Panel(self)  

    self.buttonExit = wx.Button(self.panelSide, label="exit")
    self.buttonExit.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnExitButton)

    cur = self.parent.con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM " + EMPLOYEETABLE + " ORDER BY Name;")
    self.rows = cur.fetchall()#Load all the employees into self.rows and organize by name

    self.employeenumber = len(self.rows) #Going to be the fetched number from the database
    global TOTALEMPLOYEES 
    TOTALEMPLOYEES = self.employeenumber

    #Set up all the column panels and place into an array to be modified
    #self.empGrid = empGrid(self.panelMain)
    self.empGrid = empGrid(EMP.MainWindow.panel2)
    for i in xrange (0, TOTALEMPLOYEES):
        self.empGrid.SetRowLabelValue(i, str(i+1))
        for j in xrange (0,12):
            self.empGrid.SetCellValue(i, j, str(self.rows[i][j]))
            if i % 2 == 1:#if it is odd, change the color to make it easier on the eyes
                self.empGrid.SetCellBackgroundColour(i, j, 'LIGHT BLUE') #JTEST

    self.empGrid.Bind(wx.grid.EVT_GRID_CELL_LEFT_DCLICK, self.OnGridDoubleClick)
    self.empGrid.Bind(wx.grid.EVT_GRID_CELL_RIGHT_DCLICK, self.OnGridDoubleClickRight)

    #Now do the same thing for the buttons
    text = wx.StaticText(self.panelSide, label = "Double left click an employee to modify fields\n\n\n  Double right click an employee to add a new employee task" , size = (wx.EXPAND,400))        
    sideSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)        
    sideSizer.Add(text)
    sideSizer.Add(self.buttonExit)
    self.panelSide.SetSizer(sideSizer)
    self.panelSide.Layout()


    #Put them all together then display
    displayEmployeeSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    displayEmployeeSizer.Add(self.empGrid) #JGRID
    self.panelMain.SetSizer(displayEmployeeSizer)
    self.panelMain.Layout() 

    viewEmployeeSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    #viewEmployeeSizer.Add(self.panelTitle,proportion=0)
    viewEmployeeSizer.Add(self.panelMain,proportion=0)
    viewEmployeeSizer.Add(self.panelSide,proportion = 0)
    #viewEmployeeSizer.Add(self.buttonPanel, proportion=0, flag = wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
    #viewEmployeeSizer.Add(self.buttonExit, proportion = 0, flag = wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL)

    self.SetSizer(viewEmployeeSizer) #Set the panel size
    #self.buttonPanel.Layout()        
    self.Layout()
    self.Show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't show the exact same widget in two different parents. Instead, you will need to create an instance of the empGrid when you create your standalone frame AND a different instance when you create the notebook.

When you instantiate the empGrid, you pass it the the notebook panel/page as its parent. When you create the frame, you will pass the frame (or its panel) as the parent.

Comment: I ended up getting my desired result in a lot more simple code than I thought, essentially "tab2 = empGrid(notebook)" (thanks for the push in the right direction Mike!), but the final hurdle is populating the empGrid in the main window tab with the information used in the EmployeeViewAllFrame class.  Is there a similar parent/child pairing that needs to happen so that when empGrid is called in my main file, it fills itself with the results of the EVAF methods and for loops and only then will display itself in the tab?

Comment: If you are loading the information into memory, then you could do that in your main program and pass that to the **empGrid** class each time you instantiate it. That way you only have to do the query once. I was also reading about caching recently which would also be a good way to do this. See the following article: http://pydanny.com/cached-property.html

Comment: I think I'm following you here, but does the process change if the data from the CSV file is first loaded into an SQL database server and then the information used to populate the grid is pulled from there?  That seemed to be the root cause of my problem with the 'con' attribute, which is the connection to the SQL database, because it wasn't declared as globally, and even then it needs to make a connection to the server before it can be considered active.

Comment: You can connect to the server in your main frame's init. If the query takes a long time, that's where I would do it (or put it into a thread). Then when you've got your data, you pass it on to empGrid. Basically you would modify empGrid so it would would accept a "data" argument and do your loop that you have in EmployeeViewAllFrame inside of empGrid instead. Or if you want to query the database each time you create an instance of empGrid, then create the conn object in the main init and pass the conn object to empGrid.